# How does the class atribute work for fragments and regular views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

Why does the `fragment` has the attribute `class` but an `ImageView` doesn't have it? Why do we need this `class` attribute? For example, consider:

```
<fragment class="com.expample.testfragment.Title"
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

and also:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Img1"  
    android:layout_width="150dp" 
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> why the Fragment has the attribute class=""

You need it to specify the path(in the form of package where the `fragment` class is declared and the actual name of the `fragment` class) to the class that represents that fragment in the layout(so the system can instantiate it for your, build the UI etc).

> but the ImageView doesn't have?

You can set the class attribute for an `ImageView`(or other views) but it will be ignored, it wouldn't make any sense to have it, the system knows where to find the view.

The `class` attribute can be used to declared custom views in the layout like this:

```
<view class="package.here.to.custom.view.CustomView" <!-- other attributes --> />
```

This would be useful if you have the custom view declared as a nested class in another class.